# Faster way to split up video and remerge clips using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, split, concatenation, video-processing, video-encoding

I'm trying to take a video file (mp4, mkv), split it up into frame-accurate smaller clips and re-merge those clips together into a single video without losing much quality and keeping a similar filesize and all that as fast as possible.

The clips can get very short (less than a second) and I need them to be frame-accurate. Therefore it seems that using `-c copy` as encoder isn't an option, as cutting by keyframe isn't accurate enough in this case. (Tried it out, doesn't work, input/output seeking didn't make a big difference)

Right now I am re-encoding them when splitting the video up with `-c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast`, and on merge I then use `-c copy`, which takes a lot of time but I wonder if there is a faster way to do the same thing. I tried using the concat-demuxer or directly reencoding from the original video using a file with the original videoname and timestamps but no luck.

1. Is there a way to make this two step process faster (cutting -> merging)?
2. Is there a way to directly merge sections of the original video together without need of intermediate clips, possibly making the process faster?

(I looked out for other tools than ffmpeg, but it seems like there isn't anything out that can do any better)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough rep to comment but I just wanted to ask that if you can provide me what code are you currently using, then I may help with it.

Comment: Cutting: `ffmpeg -ss 63.4 -i inputfile.mp4 -t 1.4 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast splitX.mp4`, Merging: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i splitlist.txt -c copy outputfile.mp4` where splitlist contains a list of all the splits wich I previously extracted